# formulario no funciona

Tags: javascript

tengo una validación de formulario muy sencilla, pero no funciona y no soy capaz de ver por qué. Cuando presiono submit, va la cabecera de la página en vez de desplegar el parrafo con el mensaje.

```js
document.getElementById("warning").style.display = 'none';

function validacion() {

  let nombre = document.getElementById("campoNombre").value;
  let email = document.getElementById("campoEmail").value;
  

  if (nombre === null ||  email === null || nombre.length === 0 || email.length === 0) {

            document.getElementById("warning").style.display = 'block';

            return false;
            
            } 
      };
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">

<h3>Solicitar información</h3>


  <form method="POST" id="formulario" onsubmit="return validacion();">

Nombre:<br><input type="text" name="name" id="campoNombre"><br>

Email:<br><input type="text" name="mail" id="campoEmail"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Solicitar información" name="submit" id="submit">

</form> 
</div>

<div>
<p id="warning">No se enviaron los datos</p>
</div>
```

¿Alguien puede echarme un cable?

Comment: puedes poner algo más sencillo: `if (!nombre || !email) { ...}` y funcionará

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que tus validaciones no son del todo correctas.

***nombre === null*** // nunca se va a ejecutar ya que cuando no escribes
nada esto devuelve un string vacio

***email.length === ""*** // el .length devuelve un numero asi que deberias validar que sea igual a 0

Ejemplo de como lo resolvi:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">

<h3>Solicitar información</h3>


  <form method="POST" id="formulario" onsubmit=" validacion(); return false;">

Nombre:<br><input type="text" name="name" id="campoNombre"><br>

Email:<br><input type="text" name="mail" id="campoEmail"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Solicitar información" name="submit" id="submit">

</form> 
</div>

<div>
<p id="warning">No se enviaron los datos</p>
</div>
```

Tener en cuenta el return false dentro del onSubmit para que no salte la pagina al inicio

```
document.getElementById("warning").style.display = 'none';

function validacion(e) {

  let nombre = document.getElementById("campoNombre").value;
  let email = document.getElementById("campoEmail").value;


  if (nombre === "" || email === "" || nombre.length === 0 || email.length === 0) {

            document.getElementById("warning").style.display = 'block';

            }
 };
```

Enlace a codepen https://codepen.io/renzo-brian-telenta-visconte/pen/ydgzYg

Comment: Perfecto, gracias. He cambiado el length a cero ya que con tantas ediciones lo había copiado mal.

Answer (score 2):

puedes validar usando `=== ""` además de la función `trim()` para eliminar espacios, de esta forma funcionaría correctamente, pero debes evitar usar la comparación  `=== null`  la cual no funcionaría correctamente :

```
if (nombre.trim() === "" ||  email.trim() === "") {
```

Revisa el código:

```js
document.getElementById("warning").style.display = 'none';

function validacion() {

  let nombre = document.getElementById("campoNombre").value;
  let email = document.getElementById("campoEmail").value;
  
  if (nombre.trim() === "" ||  email.trim() === "") {

            document.getElementById("warning").style.display = 'block';

            return false;
            
            } 
      };
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">

<h3>Solicitar información</h3>


  <form method="POST" id="formulario" onsubmit="return validacion();">

Nombre:<br><input type="text" name="name" id="campoNombre"><br>

Email:<br><input type="text" name="mail" id="campoEmail"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Solicitar información" name="submit" id="submit">

</form> 
</div>

<div>
<p id="warning">No se enviaron los datos</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en la sentencia.

La operación lógica `||` tiene que venir dada por esto para que funcione:

```
si name es nulo || edad es nulo || nombre está vacío || edad está vacío {}
```

Dado el anterior pseudocódigo, el código vendría dado por el siguiente funcionamiento:

```js
function validate()
{
  var input = document.getElementById('name').value;
  
  if(input == null || input == '')
  {
    document.getElementById('warning').style.display = 'block';
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

dialog {
  background-color: #ff9f0a99;
  border: .125em solid #ff9500;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 2em;
}

form {
  background-color: #f2f2f7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 75%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <dialog id="warning">Debes completar el campo.</dialog>
  <form method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <h1>Rellenar formulario</h1>
    <input id="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
</body>
```

Te recomiendo utilizar las ventajas que proporciona HTML ante casos de validación de formularios, que puedes encontrar [aquí](https://girliemac.com/blog/2012/11/21/html5-form-validation/).

Comment: Creo que es más correcto usar === null en vez de == null, pero lo más correcto es usar !input

Comment: ¿Qué significa !input, lo contrario al valor del input? Desconocía ese método.